# How can I add term's vocabulary name as body class?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I already had following codes added, which adds term ID as body class. However, how can I change the ID to term's vocabulary name?

For example:

> <body class="term-type-cameras">

```php
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    // Load the term entity and get the data from there.
    $term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term');
    $variables['term_id'] = $term->id();
    $variables['vocabulary_id'] = $term->bundle();
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'term-' . $term->id();
  }
}
```

Comment: The original code looked like you did this in the Claro theme code. I hope that was just a sample and you created your own custom theme or module for that. Never hack core or contrib. Changes will get lost on the next update.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx, I did build my site based on Claro, but it's really my first ever time to know that...Appreciate your reminder!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$term->bundle()`](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/bundles#:%7E:text=In%20Drupal%208%2C%20bundles%20are,they%20fit%20below%20entity%20types.) method to get term vocabulary and then use it as part of the class.

```php
$variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'term-type-' . $term->bundle();
```

Comment: You should pass the `$term->bundle()` through [cleanCssIdentifier](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3AcleanCssIdentifier/8.2.x)